# Does anaconda change package list for new enviroment?

Tags: python, anaconda

When I create new virtual env it shows the packages which will be installed.
It shows long list but sometimes it shows short list instead.
Also, the process is done really fast.
What causes this difference?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. This question is nearly impossible to answer without some more specifics. Can you please post the exact command you're running and its associated output? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know about the additional options when I create a new environment.
The one I thought fast, had no options.
And the other one had some like tensorflow, keras.